# Setting Value for ValidForm Builder

Tags: php

I am trying to give an email field a value gathered from the database, but it's not working as a $meta entry and there no documentation on how to set the value:

```
    //*** Special e-mail address validation
    $objForm->addField("paypal_id","Paypal Account", VFORM_EMAIL,
        array("required" => false),
        array("type" => "This is not a valid e-mail address!"),
        array("tip" => "Your paypal account email address", "value"=>"test") //not working
    );
```

Anyone have any experience with this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used default instead of value in the $meta array

Answer (score 3):

*I am one of the developers who created ValidForm Builder.*

The "default" meta value is the way to go. You can optionally set a "hint" meta value instead of the 'default' to set a default value that cannot be submitted as a value (it will not validate).

```
//*** Using the 'default' meta
$objForm->addField("paypal_id","Paypal Account", VFORM_EMAIL,
    array("required" => false),
    array("type" => "This is not a valid e-mail address!"),
    array(
        "tip"     => "Your paypal account email address", 
        "default" => "Default value" // Valid value to submit
    ) 
);

//*** Using the 'hint' meta
$objForm->addField("paypal_id","Paypal Account", VFORM_EMAIL,
    array("required" => false),
    array("type" => "This is not a valid e-mail address!"),
    array(
        "tip"     => "Your paypal account email address", 
        "hint"    => "Hint value" // Will trigger an error if 'Hint value' is submitted
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    //*** Special e-mail address validation
    $objForm->addField("paypal_id","Paypal Account", VFORM_EMAIL,
        array("required" => false),
        array("type" => "This is not a valid e-mail address!"),
        array("tip" => "Your paypal account email address", "default"=>"test") 
    );
```